# I can't move to the next screen in application with an actionbar image

Tags: robotium

I'm new in Robotium testing. And I encountered with a problem: we have the functionality to post some theme. We don't have buttons in the application to move to the next screen, only generated actionbar with Next option. 
Please, can you help me how can I click on this Next option to move to the next screen?

Here is my test:

```
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.part_tab_post));
    solo.enterText(0, "Listing new from Julina");
    solo.enterText(1, "description from Julina");
```

//      solo.getView(R.id.actionbar_post); - but this doesn't help

Here is the code which includes lines related to actionbar:

```
private void initActionBar() {
    actionBarPostListing = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_post);
    actionBarPostListing.setTitle(R.string.post_listing);
    actionBarPostListing.addAction(new ActionPostListingNext());
}

/** Action to next button on the Post a Listing actionbar.*/
private class ActionPostListingNext extends AbstractAction {

    public ActionPostListingNext() {
        super(R.drawable.btn_states_action_next);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encounter this problem also and I had to use the standard android framework to get this to work like so:

```
View view = activity.findViewById(R.id.part_tab_post);
runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    view.requestFocus();
  }
};
TouchUtils.clickView(this, view);
```

Then you can enter your text with robotium

```
//solo.waitForActivity(activityName);
//or
//solo.waitForFragmentById(fragmentId);
solo.enterText(0, "Listing new from Julina");
solo.enterText(1, "description from Julina");
```